# Upload Facebook profile image with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby, facebook, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I'm trying to use the Facebook profile image with Devise, uploading it to S3 with CarrierWave / fog, but the link I'm getting from Facebook provided in `auth.info.image` is a link to download the file, not an image that CarrierWave can use.

If you go to the link in a browser, it is a file download link. I've not seen any articles anywhere that address this. I thought I could use CarrierWave to download the file to `/tmp`, then upload it, but calls to `CarrierWave::Uploader::Download` do not work. Or I've seen other articles explaining that you can save the link provided by Facebook just use that in an `= image_tag` but that doesn't work, either.

In my `User` model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create! do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.password_confirmation = user.password
      user.profile_image = auth.info.image
    end
end
```

but `user.profile_image` is `nil`. I have no problem with `CarrierWave` - I've used it on several other projects to save to AWS with fog.

I would like to either a) save a link to the image that I can use in a Rails view, but as mentioned already, I do not have that - the link returned by Facebook is a link to download an image, so, b) is to download the file, save the filename to the User model and upload the file to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"#{auth.info.image}?type=large"` instead of `auth.info.image`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `CarrierWave` has its own magic, whereby if you prepend the field name with `remote_` and append it with `_url` it knows to download a file before uploading. So, my field name is `profile_image`, and (in my `User` model) `self.from_omniauth(auth)` method:

`user.remote_profile_image_url = auth.info.image`

just works. The field name has the correct filename saved to it, and the files (full size and thumbnail) are uploaded to S3.